# comments inside jquery inside more jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have some jquery inside the html area of another thing of jquery.html, and I need to put

```
 target='blank'
```

, but I already used both ' and ". How can I use yet another string in both of those strings?

Comment: show your html and js code. It is unclear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use escaping.

```
var text = "Something \"with quotes\"";
```